# Apache Mod_Rewrite needs to keep the Path but change the Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

## Background

I have a website that has several other alias domain names, in an effort to streamline and simplify I want all the domains to revert to the one domain name I now advertise -

Main name: `www.explorerWorld.co.uk`

Other names that load the same content but retain their own address:

`www.exploreElsewhere.co.uk`

`www.exploitedexplodedexplorers.co.uk`

what I have is that across the internet there are links in peoples blogs and elsewhere that go to specific pages on my site, but these will be under these different domains.

I have changed the domain Alises under cPanel and this works, for the base address only, but a domain for example `www.exploreElsewhere.co.uk/trees.php` does not redirect.

## Question

I would like these pages to still work but to redirect to the main site -- www.explorerWorld.co.uk  -- * but preserving their file path*

so: `www.exploreElsewhere.co.uk/plants/trees.php` gets seemlessly changed to `www.explorerWorld.co.uk/plants/trees.php`

My htaccess so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^exploreWorlds\.co\.uk$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exploreWorlds.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this seems to work in an endlessly repeating loop, How can I improve this htaccess ?

I have also looked here but this was not very helpful: 
[.htaccess change domain but keep path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302103/htaccess-change-domain-but-keep-path?s=1|4.0303)

Comment: Try changing the `RewriteCond` to `!^(www\.)?exploreworlds\.co\.uk`. The `$1` is probably not doing what you think it is so you can remove it, or at the least make it only `$`

Comment: thanks @arco444 , the redirect now works but it does not preserve the domain path. I have had a fiddle and I found a solution using `%{REQUEST_URI}` . Cheers for the nudge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem was to use `%{REQUEST_URI}` which is the path given to the server.

*(with a pointer from Arco444)*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?exploreworlds\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.exploreworlds.co.uk/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This successfully rewrites the domain part of the URL to force alias URL links to be redirected to my base website address + path

Comment: I suggest that you remove the slash in front of %{REQUEST_URI}. That environment parameter already contains a leading slash! Also your RewriteRule matching pattern ^(.*) can be shorter and more efficient: to match anything you can use a single caret. So you end up with: `RewriteRule ^ http://www.exploreworlds.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your RewriteCond. Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.exploreWorlds\.co\.uk$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exploreWorlds.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

instead, or remove the tilda from your original snippet

Comment: there is no tilda in the original code? also your rewrite rule looks exactly the same as the one in my question.

Comment: Not so look at you RewriteCond RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^exploreWorlds\.co\.uk$1 [NC]           It doesn't have the www.

Comment: Ok. I don't see the WWW as being an issue, as the issue was to maintain the path structure rather than the subdomain! And by tilda  do you mean exclamation mark ! ?

Comment: Sorry - I mean caret. In a rewrite rule it acts as a start anchor for a regular expression.